# How to update all GCP projects incorrect label for a particular folder with correct labels

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a requirement below for GCP:

1. Find all the projects under a particular folder with labels attached. (i.e. Key/value) -- already had a list
2. update the incorrect labels "keys" with correct labels
3. update the incorrect label "values" with correct label values
4. if the label does not present in that project, it should create the labels

Preferring power-shell script but no hard rule as such

Comment: You can list all projects in a specific folder with labels attached with the command below:                                                                                                  gcloud projects list --filter="parent.id:FOLDER_ID AND labels:*"                   The gcloud command below will update all labels given and create them if there is none:                                                                                 gcloud alpha projects update PROJECT_ID--update-labels=[KEY=VALUE, ...]
Is this close to what you are attempting to accomplish?

Comment: @Gustavo: thanks for the update. Let me check on this one. Need to apply the loop to update all projects at once. Will update you

Comment: @Gustavo The issue here is that if we update a key, value must be specified. Even though we can leave it as blank but it overrides the previous value. My requirement is to only update the key in all projects. while looping if that key is already found it will override the value to default which will be an issue. How to over-ride a key with keeping the value untouched. Because the same key has different values in different projects

Comment: It seems calling even the API directly [1] performs the same action. There does not seem to be a way to set only the key without changing the value.                                                                            
[1]:https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/update